# Deconstruct return value of function into an array

Tags: solidity

I'm studying solidity and I'm trying to understand arrays and destructuring. is it possible to deconstruct returns of functions into arrays ? if so how can that be achieved?

Say I have a function named `function someFunction(uint arg1, uint arg2) external returns (uint, uint, uint){// some logic // }` I want to destructure the return values into an array.
The only way I'm able to do this is by declaring an array, destructuring the return values of someInfo into their own values and then assigning each slot in the array a destructured value.

```
uint[3] memory someArray;

(uint var1, uint var2, uint var3) = someFunction(//some inputs //);
someArray[0] = var1;
someArray[1] = var2;
someArray[2] = var3;
```

Is there a better way of achieving this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Solidity currently (v0.8) doesn't allow deconstructing from multiple variables to an array.

Only simplification you can do in your example is to assign to the array items directly.

```
uint[3] memory someArray;
(someArray[0], someArray[1], someArray[2]) = someFunction();
```